# How can I know google sync is activated on an android device programmatically?

Tags: android

I need to know 2 things :

1. Does google sync currently active on a device.
2. If yes , when was the last backup Datetime.

so far I didn't find a way to get a hand on this data , any help will be appreciated.
I don't mind if it's a solution that will work only from a particular API version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)**, filtering its results by account type (*com.google*), but above all by sync state, using a [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAutomatically%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29).

Check out the code attached:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");        
boolean syncEnabled = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(accounts[0], ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
seems like event if the whole sync service on the device is turned off that boolean is true.
the only way I get a false on that one is by manually unchecking all the checkboxes for the google account sync.

I'm looking for something that will return false in case the device sync is off.

in addition I also need the last sync datetime

Answer (score 1):

Three methods are useful to know if sync is activated and enabled:

- [`ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getMasterSyncAutomatically%28%29) returns true if sync
  is enabled for the whole device.
- [`ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(yourAccount, TheProviderYouWant.AUTHORITY))`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getIsSyncable%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) returns a value > 0 if the provider is syncable
- [`ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(yourAccount, TheProviderYouWant.AUTHORITY)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAutomatically%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) returns true if sync is currently enabled for this provider. But be careful to also check `getMasterSyncAutomatically()`, because `getSyncAutomatically()` can return true even if `getMasterSyncAutomatically()` returns false